# Recursive GCD Logic Error

Tags: c, recursion, logic, greatest-common-divisor

As far as I can tell the logic in this makes sense. Yet the output is incorrect and I can seem to make sense of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int, int);

int main()
{
    int n, m;

    printf("enter two numbers");
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);

    printf("The gcd of %d and %d is: %d \n", n, m, gcd(n,m));

    return 0;
}

int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    while(x!=y){
           if(x>y)
                    return (x-y,y);

            else
                    return(x,y-x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a *recursive* implementation of `gcd`, the function is not calling itself and besides it's using a `while` loop. A truly recursive approach will look like this:

```
int gcd(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0)
        return x;
    else
        return gcd(y, x % y);
}
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
int gcd(int x, int y) {
    return y == 0 ? x : gcd(y, x % y);
}
```

The above implementation is based on the Euclidean algorithm, refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) for more details.

Comment: could it be written another way without using a ? b : c

Comment: Sure, `?:` is a shorthand for `if-else`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (x-y,y);
```

will simply return `y`. That code compiles, but probably does not what you expected.

A non-recursive Euclid GCD algorithm would look like this:

```
int gcd (int x, int y)
{
    while (y != 0)
    {
        int r = x % y;
        x = y;
        y = r;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Compared with a recursive version :

```
int gcd (int x, int y)
{
    return y == 0 ? x : gcd (y, x%y);
}
```

As always in these trivial examples, the recursive approach uses less source code but is inefficient.

Copies of `x` and `y` plus the return address are passed on the stack, while the linear version simply works with an intermediate variable `r` for the remainder of `x / y`.

Even if some compilers might be smart enough to detect the unnecessary recursion and optimize it away, I think it is useful to understand the inherent cost of recursive coding.